# Adding a client certificate to a single node service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-service-fabric

I've got a development cluster, and I want to add a (readonly) client certificate to it. When I run the appropriate powershell command:

```
PS> Add-AzServiceFabricClientCertificate `
       -ResourceGroupName $ClusterResourceGroupName `
       -Name $ClusterName `
       -Thumbprint $ClientCertThumbprint
```

I get the following error message:

```
Add-AzServiceFabricClientCertificate : Code: SingleNodeClusterUpdateNotAllowed, Message: Single node cluster update
not allowed. Updates are allowed for clusters having node count equal or greater than 3.
```

Does this mean I need to rebuild the entire cluster or is there a way to add a new client thumbprint to the cluster?

Note that I've also tried using azure portal, but I get the following error which I would guess has the same cause as above:

```
 Failed to submit updates for certificate
 Failed to submit updates to 'read-only client certificate' for 'xxxxxx'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you created the cluster as a single node cluster, you won't be able to update the cert. You would need to rebuild the cluster and opt to not use a single node cluster. Instead you would pick a 3 node cluster which is also suggested for development.

Comment: Well that's annoying